# How can I get the value of the last th?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I need to print the word of `Emails` on click of all checkboxes. How can I do that? Here is my HTML structure:

```js
$('td input').on('change', function() {
  var header_name = $(this).closests('tr').sibilings('th').last().text();
  console.log(header_name);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th><input type="checkbox" class="all_checkboxes"></th>
      <th>Emails</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" data-id="email"></td>
      <td>email</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" data-id="gmail"></td>
      <td>gmail</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" data-id="aol"></td>
      <td>aol</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" data-id="chmail"></td>
      <td>chmail</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: A `<th>` element is not the brother/sister of a `<tr>` element

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly you have a couple of typos. `closests()` should be `closest()` and `sibilings()` needs to be `siblings()`.

The issue itself is because your DOM traversal is not correct. You're trying to look at sibling `th` of the parent `tr` to the clicked `input`, when the `th` you're aiming for is in a completely different row.

To fix this you should use `closest()` to get the `table`, then `find()` the `tr:last`, like this:

```js
$('td input').on('change', function() {
  var header_name = $(this).closest('table').find('th:last').text();
  console.log(header_name);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th><input type="checkbox" class="all_checkboxes"></th>
      <th>Emails</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" data-id="email"></td>
      <td>email</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" data-id="gmail"></td>
      <td>gmail</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" data-id="aol"></td>
      <td>aol</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" data-id="chmail"></td>
      <td>chmail</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody>
       <tr>
          <th><input type="checkbox" class="all_checkboxes"></th>
          <th>Emails</th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" data-id="email"></td>
          <td>email</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" data-id="gmail"></td>
          <td>gmail</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" data-id="aol"></td>
          <td>aol</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" data-id="chmail"></td>
          <td>chmail</td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>    
</table>
<script>
    $('td input, th input').on('change', function(){
        var header_name = $( "tr:first" ).last().text();
        console.log(header_name);
    })
</script>
```